# How to run tests of DefinitelyTyped repository

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm-install, definitelytyped

Pulled latest [commit](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/9f0f926a12026287b5a4a229e5672c01e7549313) from master branch. 
Ran following commands referring the official [contribution guide](http://definitelytyped.org/guides/contributing.html)

```
npm install
tsc --noImplicitAny .\mongoose\mongoose-tests.ts
```

But this is giving numerous errors like

```
error TS1005: ';' expected.
error TS1006: Identifier expected; 'this' is a keyword.
error TS1008: Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement' expected.
error TS1003: Identifier expected.
error TS1005: '=>' expected.
```

Similar errors are also displayed while running tests for youtube package definition.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a `typescript` version that isn't the latest *stable release*.

Comment: tsd --version = tsd 0.6.5 (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/releases), npm ls typescript= 1.8.7 for npm (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/releases), seems latest